# Создание вкладок в приложении ios

Tags: xcode, swift

Добрый день!

Начал изучать swift. Возник вопрос: как создать кнопки в нижней части приложения?

Вот пример:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном вопросе нет никакой связи с языками программирования. Для того чтобы сделать таббар, нужно изучать матчасть, в частности iOS SDK, и если еще подробнее - [UITabBar](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2FIOS%2Fdocumentation%2FUIKit%2FReference%2FUITabBar_Class%2Findex.html&ei=k9u0VPesDMW6ygP0r4KwAw&usg=AFQjCNGZawTvSPQTmggG4Zc2ajjQxaadVg&cad=rjt).

Comment: Понял. Пойду гуглить. Спасибо